# How to Open a Database from Visual Studio Server Explorer in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

**Question Background**

I have a created a database in Visual Studio under the Server Explorer tab. This is fine but I would like to be able to open this database in SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008 in this case). I can't see the database under the database list in SQL.

**How can I open the database I've created in Visual Studio in SQL Server?**

The following diagrams show the issues:

1. The MainDB.mdf database in VS:

[image]

2. SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. The database MainDB database is not showing:

[image]

Comment: google attach mdf file to sql server

Comment: or .... just type localhost in sql when connecting

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting to two different instances. From Visual Studio, the default instance is either localhost\SQLExpress or just localhost (or just your computer name). From SQL Server Management Studio I can see that you specified something else. From the "Connect to Server" window in SQL Management Studio, choose one of the instances I mentioned above. Or alternatively, from Visual Studio, right click on "Data Connections" --> "Add Connection...", and then specify the same instance name you used to connect using SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Visual Studio 2012, here is something that changed - VS 2012 uses a **localDB** instance whenever you create a database for use within your application. So you have 2 options:
1. There is a new window called the SQL Server Object Explorer that you can use to work with your LocalDB. It provides a view of your database objects that’s similar to SQL Server Management Studio. You can access it from the **view** menu.
2. If you still want to use SSMS, you can access it by putting `(localdb)\v11.0` in server name.  More about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It should show directly in SQL Server, Unless your are using different credentials for connection. (credentials means Server Name & User)

Create new DB
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEmMB.png

Explore in sql
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxgiV.png

Can you let us know are they both same ?

You can also try 'Browse in sql server object explorer' by right clicking DB name in Visual studio